# Paginate UIWebView content

Tags: javascript, objective-c, uiwebview, pagination, epub

UIWebView is loaded with a long html. How to paginate the UIWebView, without the content or image in it getting cut? I have tried using ePubjs but not sure how it works! Can anyone help?

Comment: can you post your code please?

Comment: It is kind of integrated, unable to give it out separately. You can assume that I have loaded a page in UIWebView and trying to execute a javascript on it. Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is JavaScript file contain function for pagination google it, and also you need to inject your HTML file to insert the HTML tags needed to make the pagination function work.